# How to remove black border in prime ng panel menu that was active?

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I am using prime ng panel menu. There is black border around the active menu. I debugged the css in chrome, but I can't find the css for the border.

```
<div class="sidenav">
  <h4 style="text-align: center">Sample App</h4>

  <p-panelMenu
    [model]="items"
    [style]="{ width: '250px' }"
    [multiple]="false"
  ></p-panelMenu>
</div>
```

```
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

[image]

Comment: did you check `.sidenav a:focus` or `.sidenav a.active`?

Comment: Becky I checked .sidenav a:focus. It is not causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is not a border, but a `box-shadow`, that is visible when the `<a>` element inside `.p-panelmenu-header` is focused.

You can override the default CSS rule:

```
.p-panelmenu .p-panelmenu-header > a:focus {
   box-shadow: none;
}
```